# Using staticmethod to calculate fractions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I am doing a task where I have a class Fractions which contains functions as to how I can add, subtract, multiply and divide the fractions. I am having trouble creating the **add** function which will be adding 2 fractions and this function **must** use the staticmethod. This is the code that I have written so far:

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,num1=0,num2=0):
        self.num1=num1
        self.num2=num2
    def __str__(self):
        while self.num1>self.num2:
            a = self.num1//self.num2
            b = self.num1 % self.num2
            if self.num2==1:
                return "%s"%(self.num1)
            elif self.num1 % self.num2==0:
                return  "%s"%(self.num1/self.num2)
            else:
                return "%s+%s|%s"%(a,b,self.num2)
        if self.num1==0:
            return "0"
        elif self.num1 or self.num2 < 0 and self.num1==self.num2:
            return "-1"
        elif self.num2==1:
            return "%s"%(self.num1)
        elif self.num1==self.num2:
            return "1"
        else:    
            return "%s|%s"%(self.num1,self.num2)
    
    @staticmethod
    def add(a,b):
        a=Fraction(n,d)
        b=Fraction(num,den) 
        if a.d == b.den and a.n<a.d or b.num<b.den:
            return "%s|%s"%(a.n+b.num,a.d)
        elif a.d != b.den:
            return "%s|%s"%((a.n*b.den)+(a.d*b.num),(a.d*b.den))
```

I am facing trouble in trouble in the add function and I do not know how to make the function work.
For example:

```
Fraction.add(Fraction(1,4),Fraction(2,4))
>>> 3|4
Fraction.add(Fraction(1,5),Fraction(6,7))
>>> 1 + 2|35
```

This is what the output should look like. Could anyone guide me through the add function and how I can improve it using the staticmethod

Comment: In `Fraction.add`, `a` and `b` are already `Fraction` objects. Why are you overwriting them with new values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the arguments a and b are already Fraction objects, then you would use the attributes from them directly in your method:

```
@staticmethod
def add(a,b):
    if a.num2 == b.num2 and (a.num1 < a.num2 or b.num1 < b.num2):
        return "%s|%s"%(a.num1 + b.num1, a.num2)
    elif a.num2 != b.num2:
        return "%s|%s"%((a.num1 * b.num2) + (a.num2 * b.num1), (a.num2 * b.num2))
```

There were also a missing parenthesis in the first if clause.